# Using Xamarin Forms how would I display tabs in the middle of the screen?

Tags: xamarin

Using Xamarin Forms how would I display tabs in the middle of the screen. Something like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: look for a Segmented control.  This is not built in to XF, but there are several plugins and third party packages available

Comment: Or roll your own. It's just a grid with 2 columns of equal size and some styling.

Comment: I'm interested too, did you find a package for that?